# How to cut a sequence intro a list of lists according to a predicate using recursion

Tags: python, list

I am currently practicing recursion and a problem that i often encounter is cutting a sequence into a list of lists. I've tried to solve it by myself but without success:

My code:

```
def cut_sequence_at(seq, pred) -> list:
    if not seq:
        return [[]]
    if len(seq) == 1:
        return [seq]
    rest = cut_sequence_at(seq[1:], pred)
    if pred(seq[0]):
        return [[seq[0]] + rest[0]] + rest[1:]
    else:
        return [[seq[0]]] + rest

# input
seq = [8,6,3,4,12,8,7,2,1]
pred = lambda x: x % 2 != 0
cut_sequence_at(seq, pred)

# Output
[[8], [6], [3, 4], [12], [8], [7, 2], [1]]

# Expected output
[[8, 6], [3, 4, 12, 8], [7, 2], [1]]
```

Clearly something is wrong with my logic but I don't know how to fix it. How would you go about solving it without using non standard-lib modules?

Comment: Your `else` clause *always* creates a list of lists where the first element is a list of length 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `next()` function to find the position of the first item that meets the condition. Return that part and recurse for the rest. Finding the breaking position needs to start from the second item so that you don't generate empty parts.

```
def cut(seq,cond):
    i = next((i for i, n in enumerate(seq[1:], 1) if cond(n)), None)
    if i is None: return [seq]            # no item meeting condition
    return [seq[:i]] + cut(seq[i:], cond) # first part + recursion

seq = [8,6,3,4,12,8,7,2,1]
pred = lambda x: x % 2 != 0
print(cut(seq, pred))
[[8, 6], [3, 4, 12, 8], [7, 2], [1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic solution would be to use an iterative rather than a recursive solution. If you wanted a recursive solution that followed a Lisp-like head,tail approach, the easiest way would be by defining a recursive helper function which takes a list of chunks whose final status is settled, a currently growing chunk, and the rest of the list. It examines the head of the rest of the list. If it satisfies the predicate, the growing chunk (if nonempty) is tacked onto the list of known chunks, and a new growing chunk is initialized. Otherwise the head is tacked onto the end of the growing chunk. This has the theoretical advantage of being [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (which would matter if python optimized away tail-calls).

```
def cut_sequence_at(seq, pred):
    def helper(settled,active,rest):
        if rest == []:
            if active != []:
                settled.append(active)
            return settled
        head, tail = rest[0],rest[1:]
        if pred(head):
            if active != []:
                settled.append(active)
            active = [head]
        else:
            active.append(head)
        return helper(settled,active,tail)
    return helper([],[],seq)

seq = [8,6,3,4,12,8,7,2,1]
pred = lambda x: x % 2 != 0
print(cut_sequence_at(seq, pred)) #[[8, 6], [3, 4, 12, 8], [7, 2], [1]]
```